# Add categories to default WordPress search

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, categories

I have a search form containing select fields. The first two are populated with custom taxonomies and the third with the default wordpress categories. When using the first two only for a query it works fine. When I use the third( the categories), the search query just ignores the field and comes up with the same results. How can I fix this?

I've used these functions to make them work:

```
function ftiaxnospiti_filter_search($query) {
  if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'seller') );
    }

  return $query;
};
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'ftiaxnospiti_filter_search');

function ftiaxnospiti_add_custom_types_to_tax( $query ) {
  if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( is_category() || is_tag() && empty( $query->query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) {
    // Get all your post types
    $post_types = array( 'post', 'seller' );

    $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );
  }

  return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ftiaxnospiti_add_custom_types_to_tax' );
```